# What is $A \cup \{u\}$ if $A$ is linearly independent of a vector space $V$, $Y = L(A)$ be a subspace of V, and $u \in V - Y$?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Is $A \cup \{u\}$ linearly independent if $A$ is linearly independent subset of a vector space $V$ over the the field of real numbers, $Y = L(A)$ is a subspace of V, where $L(A) = \text{span of } A$, and $u \in V - Y$?

Attempt: Since $A$ is linearly independent, let $A= a_n x^n + ... + a_2 x^2 + a_1 x + a_0$, such that $a_n x^n + ... + a_2 x^2 + a_1 x + a_0 =0$ would imply that all $a_i$ is zero for all $i \in \{0,...,n\}$. However, I am not sure if this is valid because $A$ is not necessarily a polynomial. My biggest problem is how could I write $L(A)$, the linear span of $A$ and especially the set difference $V-Y$?

Answer (score 1):

$x^{n}$ has no meaning in a general vector space. By definition, a set of vectors is linearly independent iff every finite subset of it is linearly independent.  Suppose $A \cup \{u\}$ is not linearly independent. Then there exists a finite set $\{a_1,a_2,...,a_n\}$ of distinct elements of $A$ and scalars $c_0,c_1,..,c_n$ not all $0$ such that $c_0u+c_1a_1+..+a_nc_n=0$. If $ c_0=0$ we get a contradiction to the fact that $A$ is linearly independent. Otherwise you can solve for $u$ to finish the proof.